# How can we calculate erraticism(similar or different behavior) of a customer in Data?

Tags: python, similarity, cosine-similarity

Let's say I have a data of a customer who is doing shopping everyday in week. I want to know it's behavior in a single value that all the shopping she did was similar or different.

For example, a single value between 0-1(like a scale) can define behavior of customer, where 0 means all the shopping were different and 1 means all the shopping she did was same. So I am trying to create a new feature in the data, for each customer, there should be a value which will define the shopping behavior of customer are similar or different. So if we are using scale of 0 to 1, and value for customer is 0.8, means she does mostly similar kind of shopping and if value is 0.1 means the behavior is different and they are doing different kind of shopping every time.

Also, the number of transaction for each customer is different, some customer have data of 2 transaction and some has data of 10 transaction.

[Edited]

```
CustID    Gender Bread  Butter  Egg  Milk 
  22a       1      0       0    1     1
  22a       1      1       1    1     0
  22a       1      0       0    1     1
  22a       1      1       1    0     0
  22s       1      0       0    1     1
```

Gender is categorical dtype (having value 1, 2 or 3), and rest columns are int dtype (having values only 0 or 1).

I can get the similarity between each of the shopping with cosine_similarity or any other algorithm, but I want to define the behavior with a single value. Any ideas? I am using python.

Comment: How many columns do you have? Are modality always Boolean (0 or 1) or does it expresses how many items they have purchased?

Comment: @jlandercy This is just and example data I have shown, originally, there are more columns which has categorical and numerical data. Numerical columns also has only 0 and 1 values( got from  dummification) and it represents if they bought this product or not. Its not unit of product purchased.

Comment: So what is an estimate of the size of column space?

Comment: I am not sure what are trying to ask. Please let me know if the question is not clear. I will edit and add one more column for customerID

Comment: You are looking for a classification algorithm. To make it works it is important to know what dimensions the problem have, because it has an impact on the quality of the prediction. So the question is still the same how many columns do you have? What is the size of the feature space 10, 100, 1000?

Comment: There are 49 features I am considering. Once I will get to work around these features, I might include or exclude few features to see the difference. These 49 feature I obtained from dummification of few category dtypes columns. So all of these 49 features have only 0 or 1 values.

Comment: Also, I think I am still not clear about it, this is not a classification problem where I have  to predict, but I am trying to create a new feature, whose value could be between 0-1 or -1to1, like a scale, which can describe the erratic behavior of customer. (will edit this in question too)

Answer (score 0):

OK, here's a potential option.

Instead of similarity, I've used variance (literally).

Generate some example data:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(dict(
    feat_a=np.random.choice([0, 1], size=10),
    feat_b=np.random.choice([0, 1], size=10),
    feat_c=np.random.choice([0, 1], size=10),
    feat_d=np.random.choice([0, 1], size=10),
))
df['customer_id'] = np.random.choice(['a', 'b', 'c'], size=len(df))
df

    feat_a  feat_b  feat_c  feat_d  customer_id
0   1       1       1       0       b
1   0       1       1       1       a
2   0       1       0       0       c
3   0       1       0       0       a
4   1       1       1       1       b
5   1       1       0       1       a
6   1       1       1       1       c
7   1       1       1       0       c
8   0       0       1       1       c
9   1       1       1       1       b
```

Compute the variance of each column, grouped by `customer_id` and then take the row sum.

```
total_var = df.groupby('customer_id').var().sum(axis=1)
total_var.name = 'total_var'
```

Join the result back with the original data, normalising to between 0 and 1.

```
result = pd.merge(df, total_var, left_on='customer_id', right_index=True)
result.total_var = result.total_var / result.total_var.max()
result

    feat_a  feat_b  feat_c  feat_d  customer_id  total_var
0   1       0       1       0       a            0.888889
5   1       0       0       1       a            0.888889
9   0       1       1       1       a            0.888889
1   0       1       0       1       b            1.000000
6   1       1       1       0       b            1.000000
2   1       0       1       0       c            0.400000
3   1       0       0       1       c            0.400000
4   1       0       0       1       c            0.400000
7   1       0       1       0       c            0.400000
8   1       0       1       0       c            0.400000
```

It's not exactly the most principled approach but I think it meets the requirements of the question.

One major issue, if this is meant to be used as a predictive feature, is the low variance of the `total_variance` column itself, but that's always going to be the case if the metric is to be a single value per customer.

Comment: True, low variance will always be the case. Thanks for sharing this. But as you mentioned its not most principled approach. Also, taking sum of variance, I don't know how effective it will be because if there are more entries will be there for a customer the value will be high. Mean will be better than sum I think. Good effort though, Thank you for that.

Comment: Sure thing @Sajid, hopefully it will prompt some more ideas/answers for you.  And if I think of anything else, I'll let you know.  Also, just to note that the variance is totalled across columns, so the result is independent of the number of samples per customer (and dependent on the number of features).